# Jquery Div slider loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have a small problem. Div slides and reaching end it's quickly show div 1 without pause. Div 5 cannot see.

```
$(function(){

var width = '100vw';
var speed = 1500;
var pause = 3000;
var current = 1;

var $slider = $('.slider');
var $slides = $slider.find('.slides');
var $slide = $slides.find('.slide');

setInterval(function(){
    $slides.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, speed, function(){
        current++;
        if(current == $slide.length){
            $slides.css('margin-left', 0); 
            current = 1;
        }
    });
}, pause);
});
```

But if I add delay

```
   if(current == $slide.length){
            $(this).delay(pause).queue(function(){
                $slides.css('margin-left', 0); 
            });
            current = 1;
        }
```

```js
$(function(){

    var width = '100vw';
    var speed = 1500;
    var pause = 3000;
    var current = 1;

    var $slider = $('.slider');
    var $slides = $slider.find('.slides');
    var $slide = $slides.find('.slide');

    setInterval(function(){
        $slides.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, speed, function(){
            current++;
            if(current == $slide.length){
                $(this).delay(pause).queue(function(){
                    $slides.css('margin-left', 0); 
                });
                current = 1;
            }
        });
    }, pause);

});
```

```css
.slider {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .slides {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    /*
    scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(300px);
    scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
    */
  }
  .slides::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 1px;
    height: 10px;
  }
  .slides::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #bbb;
  }
  .slides::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent;
  }
  .slides > div {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #eee;
    transform-origin: center center;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    position: relative; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 100px;
  }
  .slides > div:target {
  /*   transform: scale(0.8); */
  }
  .author-info {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    color: white;
    padding: 0.75rem;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .author-info a {
    color: white;
  }
  img {
    object-fit: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .slider > a {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    background: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid green;
  }
  .slider > a:active {
    top: 1px;
  }
  .slider > a:focus {
    background: #666;
  }
  /* Don't need button navigation */
  @supports (scroll-snap-type) {
    .slider > a {
      display: none;
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">  
  <div class="slides">
    <div id="slide-1" class="slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div id="slide-2" class="slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div id="slide-3" class="slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div id="slide-4" class="slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div id="slide-5" class="slide">Slide 5</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

It's show Div 5 like it needed, but after showing div 1 it's not sliding anymore.

So what can I do to keep looping and shows each div given time?

Maybe someone can show how can make slider slide backwards after reaching last div and slides back to div one?

Comment: post the whole code here

Comment: No one can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First : BAD solution for your problem :** ( go to Second)

Your animation code stucks in a queue once the `current == $slide.length` , you should pass the next function as argument in the queue calback then use `next()` to trigger other function . as below :

```
if(current == $slide.length){
    $(this).delay(pause).queue(function(next){ //<--- here next argument
        $slides.css('margin-left', 0); 
        next(); // <----- next call 
    });
    current = 1;
}
```

but this will not make the annimation work as expected

**Second : proper simple solution**

What I suggest is, set the animation left value as variable, then  check if it's the last so slide to 0 other wise continue left view-width sliding

See working snippet :

```js
$(function(){

    var width = '100vw';
    var speed = 1500;
    var pause = 3000;
    var current = 1;

    var $slider = $('.slider');
    var $slides = $slider.find('.slides');
    var $slide = $slides.find('.slide');

    var leftAnnime =  '-='+width;
    
    setInterval(function(){
        
        $slides.animate({'margin-left': leftAnnime }, speed, function(){
            current++;
            if( current == $slide.length ) {
              leftAnnime = 0;
              current = 0;
            } else {
              leftAnnime = '-='+width;
            }
        });
    }, pause);

});
```

```css
.slider {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .slides {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    /*
    scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(300px);
    scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
    */
  }
  .slides::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 1px;
    height: 10px;
  }
  .slides::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #bbb;
  }
  .slides::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent;
  }
  .slides > div {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #eee;
    transform-origin: center center;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    position: relative; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 100px;
  }
  .slides > div:target {
  /*   transform: scale(0.8); */
  }
  .author-info {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    color: white;
    padding: 0.75rem;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .author-info a {
    color: white;
  }
  img {
    object-fit: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .slider > a {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    background: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid green;
  }
  .slider > a:active {
    top: 1px;
  }
  .slider > a:focus {
    background: #666;
  }
  /* Don't need button navigation */
  @supports (scroll-snap-type) {
    .slider > a {
      display: none;
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">  
  <div class="slides">
    <div id="slide-1" class="slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div id="slide-2" class="slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div id="slide-3" class="slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div id="slide-4" class="slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div id="slide-5" class="slide">Slide 5</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @aidron does this help you !

Comment: Hey! Thanks! Works great! Can You please tell how can modify this to continuous loop and how to: after reaching end, slides slide back (like now) but at the same speed witch moves forward

Comment: @aidron , great , but for the new requirement this should be better a new question , in order to not ovride this answer requirement , if you can link me here new question

Comment: Ok! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64836385/slider-animations