# jQuery animated slider endless loop

Tags: jquery, loops, slider, jquery-animate

How this slider can make loop endlessly? Right now it's slides to last slide and quickly slides back, but how can make that, after reaching last slide, next slide is first again? Like 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3... etc
Is it posible to do it without heavy rebuild for jquery?
Nothing to say more about, but this site don't allow post this question, because text is too short... :D

```js
$(function(){

    var width = '100vw';
    var speed = 1500;
    var pause = 3000;
    var current = 1;

    var $slider = $('.slider');
    var $slides = $slider.find('.slides');
      var $slide = $slides.find('.slide');
    
      var leftMargin = '-='+width;
      var direction = 'left';
  
  
    setInterval(function(){
          $slides.animate({'margin-left': leftMargin}, speed, function(){
            current++;
            if(current == $slide.length){
                leftMargin = 0;
                current = 0;
            }else{
                leftMargin = '-='+width;
            }
          });
      }, pause);
  
  });
```

```css
.slider {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .slides {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    /*
    scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(300px);
    scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
    */
  }
  
  .slides::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 1px;
    height: 10px;
  }
  .slides::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #bbb;
  }
  .slides::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent;
  }
  .slides > div {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #eee;
    transform-origin: center center;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    position: relative; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 100px;
  }
  .slides > div:target {
  /*   transform: scale(0.8); */
  }
  
  .author-info {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    color: white;
    padding: 0.75rem;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .author-info a {
    color: white;
  }
  img {
    object-fit: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .slider > a {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    background: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid green;
  }
  .slider > a:active {
    top: 1px;
  }
  .slider > a:focus {
    background: #666;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">  
  <div class="slides">
    <div id="slide-1" class="slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div id="slide-2" class="slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div id="slide-3" class="slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div id="slide-4" class="slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div id="slide-5" class="slide">Slide 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are zillion slider plugins out there (most of them are free and open source), why you want to create your plugin/slider?

Comment: Because i want my own slider, who is simple and without unnecessary functions! Is it bad?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64651882/jquery-div-slider-loop

Comment: @aidron in my opinion yes, you can spend your time on parts that matter, also you can not test your plugin in all browsers and devices, but other guy's plugins on the other hand are already battle-tested _not all of them of course, but you have option to choose based on github's start, open issues and ..._.